# SwiftUI retry Alert race condition

Tags: swift, swiftui, async-await

Given the following code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var result = "Hello, world!"
    @State private var showAlert = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            Text(result)
        }
        .padding()
        .task {
            await load()
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $showAlert) {
            Alert(
                title: Text("Error"),
                message: Text("Something went wrong"),
                primaryButton: .cancel({
                }),
                secondaryButton: .default(Text("Retry")) {
                    Task { await load() }
                }
            )
        }
    }
    
    func load() async  {
        do {
//            try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1))
            result = try await Service().load()
        } catch {
            showAlert = true
        }
    }
}

class Service {
    func load() async throws -> String {
        throw "Error"
    }
}

extension String: Error {}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

The code loads some data asynchronously, and in case of error display an alert for the user to retry. The real code checks if a value is true in `UserDefaults` and throws the error, for testing purposes, otherwise actually retrieves some data that takes time (*Note*: the real code doesn't seem to reproduce on iOS 15.7, but does reproduce on iOS 16.3.1).

The problem is that when immediately throwing the error, the alert is no longer being presented. Does this happen because of a race condition between the `load` function call and the `Alert`'s binding to `showAlert`? Uncommenting the `Task.sleep` fixes the problem.

Even if throwing the error doesn't get called in production code, I'm afraid I'm misusing the `async/await` pattern somehow, and I might end up with weird issues down the line.

Comment: My guess is, dismissing the alert by tapping any of the buttons sets the `showAlert` to `false`. At the same time, the code for the Retry button sets the `showAlert` to `true` and there is a difference in implementation between different versions of iOS that causes those events to happen in one order or another.

Answer (score 0):

Having a floating `Task` like what you have in the alert button is a big issue, you should avoid it.

```
Task { await load() } //AVOID this
```

Use `.task` instead. The easier way to implement something like this is to have a `taskId` and change the ID when you want to re-run the code.

```
struct RaceThrowView: View {
    @State private var result = "Hello, world!"
    @State private var showAlert = false
    ///TaskID variable
    @State private var loadId: UUID = .init()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            Text(result)
        }
        .padding()
        //Runs "onAppear" and "onChange" of the loadId
        .task(id: loadId) {
            await load()
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $showAlert) {
            Alert(
                title: Text("Error"),
                message: Text("Something went wrong"),
                primaryButton: .cancel({
                }),
                secondaryButton: .default(Text("Retry")) {
                    //Change the loadId
                    loadId = .init()
                }
            )
        }
    }
    
    func load() async  {
        do {
            //            try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1))
            result = try await Service().load()
        } catch {
            showAlert = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Switching to using taskId, on iOS 15.7 and 16.0.3 I can tap the Retry button 20 times and it works. But on iOS 16.3.1 I can barely get to 3 taps and the Alert stop showing.

Comment: @LescaiIonel on a device? I don’t have that same behavior.

Comment: Yes, on 3 different iPhones.